# Showing 404 error while someone tries to access .php files?

Tags: php, routes

How to stop php from executing .php files while being accessed directly. I want to do routing on files and also want to stop users from directly accessing the .php files. Is there anyway to change the .htaccess file to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prevent direct access to php files**

write code in .htacess file.

```
<Directory "^public_html">
<Files "^(*.php|*.phps)">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Or

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```